# AWS Amplify configure command for different accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-cli

I am developing an AWS amplify backend for a startup. I have two aws accounts

```
1- where the startup prod resides (prod env)
2- where I test features before making any changes to the prod environment. (dev/test env)
```

In my local computer I have two amplify apps setup.

```
1- prod-app linked to prod env.
2- dev-app linked to dev env
```

The problem I am facing is I have to use amplify configure each time when I move between one account to another which makes new roles everytime. is there any way where I can tie the role and account to amplify apps and it automatically gets the required user without using amplify configure command again & again? TIA

Answer (score 4):

You should configure `Named Profiles` for use with the AWS CLI, one for each account. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html) for more information. Once you do this, re-run `amplify configure` in each project and amplify should recognize that you have profiles available and ask whether it should use one for the given project. Select the correct profile for each project and you should no longer have to run configure going forward.